# paypal get data back from webhook

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

So I'm trying to get back my `order id` from my paypal webhook. I am able to create this paypal checkout page with this code.

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_payment(request, id):
    print(os.environ.get("PAYPAL_API_KEY"))
    print(id)
    item = Product()
    discount = Discount()
    order_data = get_order_data_func(id)
    items = []
    price = 0
    for product in order_data["products"]:
        product_info = item.get_by_id(product["product"]).to_dict()
        obj = {
            "name": product_info["name"],
            "sku": product_info["name"],
            "price": int(product_info["price"]),
            "currency": "EUR",
            "quantity": product["quantity"]
        }
        price += int(product_info["price"]) * product["quantity"]
        items.append(obj)
    if order_data["order"]["discount"] is not None:
        price = price - (price * discount.get_by_id(order_data["order"]["discount"]).percentage / 100)
    payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
        "intent":"sale",
        "payer":{
            "payment_method":"paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls":{
            "return_url":"http://localhost:3000/order/success",
            "cancel_url":"http://localhost:3000/order/cancel"
        },
        "transactions":[{
            "item_list":{
                "items":items
            },
            "amount":{
                "total":price,
                "currency":"EUR"
            },
            "description":"This is the payment transaction description.",
            "custom_id": order_data["products"][0]['order']
        }]
    })
    if payment.create():
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', "url": payment.links[1].href})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'})
```

I have a webhook running using `ngrok` I also get back a response but I have not found much online on how to decrypt the response body to see all the data. This is my current function which is called through the webhook.

```
@csrf_exempt
def check_paypal_status(request):
    print(json.loads(request.body))
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
```

All help is greatly appreciated!